# Function works incorrectly when called by another function

Tags: javascript, html, function

First post here. I am trying to create an Easter Calculator for a school project. The function pasCalc(E) works great when called on its **own** on the browser console. However, when I type a year in my html **form**, all the dates are off.

Sorry if this sounds like a newb question, but I can't figure out what's wrong... Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you for your time! :)

```js
function start() {
  document.getElementById("orthodox").innerHTML = "Ορθόδοξο πάσχα:";
  //var E = document.getElementById("inputfield").value;
  //console.log(E);
  var pasxa = pasCalc(document.getElementById("inputfield").value)
  console.log(pasxa);
  //console.log(pasxa[0] + " " + pasxa[1]);

  document.getElementById("orthodox").innerHTML += " " + pasxa;
}

function pasCalc(E) {
  //var E = 2018;
  var a = E % 19;
  var T = (8 + 11 * a) % 30;
  var month = "Mach";
  var K = Math.floor((E / 100) - (E / 400) - 2);

  var iPanArx = 21 + (53 - T) % 30;

  if (iPanArx > 31) {
    var iPanArxM = iPanArx - 31;
    month = "April";
  } else {
    var iPanArxM = iPanArx;
  }

  var iPanTel = iPanArxM + K;
  var Y = (E + Math.floor(E / 4) + iPanArx) % 7;
  var iPas = iPanTel + (7 - Y);

  if (iPas > 30 && month == "April") {
    month = "May";
    var iPas = iPas - 30;
  } else if (iPas > 31 && month == "Marchυ") {
    month = "April";
    var iPas = iPas - 31;
  }
  console.log(iPas + " " + month + " " + E);
  var arr = [];
  arr.push(iPas);
  arr.push(month);
  return arr;
}
```

```html
<div class="container align-center">
  <h1>Easter Calculator</h1>
  <input id="inputfield" type="text" placeholder="Enter a Year...">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="start();">Submit</button>
  <h5 id="orthodox">Orthodox Easter:</h5>
  <h5>Catholic Easter:</h5>

</div>
```

Comment: *"all the dates are off"* Can you be more precise? What is the result you expect and what do you get? I assume the problem is that `E` is a string and not a number when reading the value from the input element.

Comment: if I input 2050 in the form I get 13 of April (the values are stored in an array for now so I can get them out of the function). When the pasCalc(E) is called on its own however, it returns 17 of April (which is the correct date for the orthodox easter).

Comment: When you call `pasCalc('2050')`  (note the quotes) in the console do you get April 13th as well?

Comment: not sure where you are getting 13th of april and 17th of april from year 2050 and your pasCalc() function. I get 48 Mach 2050 as well

Comment: @another-guy: I think you ran `pasCalc(2050)`, not `pasCalc('2050')`. The latter produces `[44, "Mach"]`.

Comment: @FelixKling I confirm that!

Comment: Please remember that document.getElementById("inputfield").value is always STRING and you may have to parse it to integer or float to use it.

Comment: Thank you all for your time and answers!

Answer (score 1):

Form fields, by default, are strings. In order for Javascript to know it's an integer so that it works with numeric calculations like the year component of a date, wrap it in a call to `parseInt()`

```
var pasxa = pasCalc(parseInt(document.getElementById("inputfield").value))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works just fine now. I will post the finished product when ready if you wanna check it out!